# Using generic handle xml and json using c#

Tags: c#

I am working on an application where I am implementing a generic method which can handle both JSON and xml which I want to handle accordingly. Below is my code.

```
public async Task<T> SendAsync<T>(ApiRequest apiRequest)
{
    try
    {
        LogRequestDetails(apiRequest);

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiRequest.data);
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(apiRequest, buffer);
        Stream post = request.GetRequestStream();

        await WriteRequestDataAsync(post, buffer);
        string responseContent = await GetResponseContentAsync(request);

        LogResponseDetails(apiRequest, responseContent);

        return HandleResponse<T>(apiRequest.contentType, responseContent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(apiRequest, ex);
        throw;
    }
}

private T HandleResponse<T>(string contentType, string responseContent)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType == "application/json")
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"API response received. API response content: {responseContent}");
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    }
    else if (contentType == "application/xml" || contentType == "text/xml")
    {
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseContent))
        {
            // Giving me error on this line.
            return  responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported media type in the Accept header.");
    }
}


#region [#PRIVATE METHODS]

private HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(ApiRequest apiRequest, byte[] buffer)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(apiRequest.url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Method = apiRequest.apiType;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRequest.contentType) || apiRequest.contentType == "application/json")
        {
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
        }
        else if (apiRequest.contentType == "application/xml" || apiRequest.contentType == "text/xml")
        {
            // Add XML-specific settings
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
            request.Accept = "gzip,deflate";
            request.UserAgent = "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)";
            request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", apiRequest.soapAction);
            request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            request.Headers.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported media type in the Accept header.");
        }
        return request;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private async Task WriteRequestDataAsync(Stream post, byte[] buffer)
{
    await post.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    post.Close();
}

private async Task<string> GetResponseContentAsync(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    string responseContent = string.Empty;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
    using (Stream responseData = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseData))
    {
        responseContent = await responseReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    return responseContent;
}

#endregion
```

I am trying to handle the method accordingly which will handle the text/xml generically. **HandleResponse** method is giving me an error on else if statement.

Comment: Where is apiRequest coming from?  You only posted a portion of the code and we cannot tell what apiRequest is really doing.  Normally you do not read a request, you read a response.  Looks like your code is some sort of relay, but only guessing.

Comment: I want to deserialize response only.

Comment: ApiRequest is a request model it contains properties like ContentType, APIType extra nothing else.

Comment: *"HandleResponse method is giving me an error"* - i do wonder, what was the error?

Comment: How to serialize the type xml stream reader and I am using generic so that is why I stuck here to figure out how to handle both json and xml using handleRequest method generically

Comment: A model is the body of a HTTP Request/Response while the Content-Type is a Header,  You should be getting the content-type from the response not from apiRequest. You request is asking for a specific type, but you should be looking at the response to get the type.

Answer (score 0):

Creates a `MemoryStream` using the encoded bytes of the response content and then utilizes `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the XML content into the specified type `T`.

```
private T HandleResponse<T>(string contentType, string responseContent)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType == "application/json")
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"API response received. API response content: {responseContent}");
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    }
    else if (contentType == "application/xml" || contentType == "text/xml")
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseContent)))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            T result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            _logger.LogInformation($"API response received. API response content: {responseContent}");
            return result;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported media type in the Accept header.");
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You can parse the XML response and extract the relevant data using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` to traverse the XML structure and extract the needed information.

```
private T HandleResponse<T>(string contentType, string responseContent)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType == "application/json")
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"API response received. API response content: {responseContent}");
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    }
    else if (contentType == "application/xml" || contentType == "text/xml")
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(responseContent);
        XElement bodyElement = xDoc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Body");

        if (bodyElement != null)
        {
            XElement specificElement = bodyElement.Element("SpecificElement");
            return (T)(object)specificElement;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Body element not found in the XML response.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported media type in the Accept header.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am receiving an error "<Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> was not expected."

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns3:createsessionResponse xmlns="http://www.utiba.com/delirium/ws/Misc" xmlns:ns2="http://www.utiba.com/delirium/ws/StdQuery" xmlns:ns3="urn:UMARKETSCWS" xmlns:ns4="http://www.utiba.com/delirium/ws/TypedQuery"><ns3:createsessionReturn><ns3:sessionid>2I4PQXT18YXD9SD06FSN</ns3:sessionid><ns3:result>0</ns3:result><ns3:result_namespace>session</ns3:result_namespace></ns3:createsessionReturn></ns3:createsessionResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>

Comment: Above is my xml and here is my CreateSessionReturn class

   public class CreateSessionReturn
   {
       [DataMember( Name = "sessionid")]
       public string? SessionId { get; set; }
       [DataMember(Name = "result")]
       public string Result { get; set; }

       [DataMember(Name = "result_namespace")]
       public string ResultNamespace { get; set; }
   }

Comment: Above error arises during XML deserialization when the XML does not match the expected structure.

Comment: what I need to change ?

Comment: Check the `update` section.

Comment: (T)(object)specificElement is null